# How to correctly set a custom 403 ERROR page in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I can't seem to figure out how to setup a custom 403 error page in Nginx for IPs that are denied.  No matter what I do, only the builtin Nginx "Forbidden" page shows up.  Below is my nginx.conf file:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;
        autoindex_localtime on;
        include ./conf/blockips.conf;

    server {
        
            listen       80;
            server_name  localhost;
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server {
            listen 443 ssl http2; 
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
            ssl_certificate     ./ssl/fullchain.cer;
            ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/cert.key;
            server_name_in_redirect off;
            log_not_found off;
            server_name  www.mywebsite.com mywebsite.com;
            
            error_page 403 /error403.html;
            location = /error403.html {
                root  html;
                allow all;
            }

        location / {
            root   /inetpub/wwwroot;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have placed the `error_page` into the wrong `server` block. Also, the URI used in the `error_page` is different to the URI used with the `location = ` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith unfortunately, making those two changes didn't make any difference at all.  No errors... only getting the default Nginx 403 Forbiden page.  There must be something else I'm missing.  I updated the OP with those changes.

Comment: Use `nginx -t` to test the configuration. You seem to have an extra `}` there. Also, did you clear the browser's cache between configuration changes?

Comment: I saw the error in the config after I tried to run it previously.  I forgot to change it in the original post here.  I just updated the OP to include the EXACT config I'm using,  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the default Nginx forbidden page; even with no errors in the config.  The only line I'm not sure about is `root html;`  It looks like there's something else wrong.  PS: I'm using the official Windows build of Nginx.